# SocketTimeoutException doesn't occur when expected

Tags: android, http, networking, long-polling

I'm working with an Android app that has rolled it's own long-polling implementation. It does this by setting the read & connection timeout on the `HttpUrlConnection.` When the `SocketTimeoutException` occurs it'll reestablish the connection. The server simply holds the connection open until it retrieves data.

I'm finding that the `SocketTimeoutException` doesn't occur when one would expect. If I set the timeout to 20s, I'll see the exception 60s later. I'm finding that (in general) in the window between the expected timeout and the exception the client never retrieves data from the server though the server logs show it sending data. I should note that the sever is written using NodeJS & express.

I suspect there are multiple issues with this current implementation. My understanding is that long-polling is usually implemented such that the server ends the connection after a set amount of time rather than the client setting a timeout on the socket.

Can anyone explain why I might be seeing this behavior?